# CSS support in Wkhtmltopdf, PDFkit

Tags: wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

Python-PDFKit is an adaption of the Ruby PDFKit library. It uses the wkhtmltopdf library for the HTML-to-PDF conversion. Unfortunately, wkhtmltopdf is based on an ancient version of WebKit and lacks support for many modern CSS and JavaScript features, such as flexbox. For that reason, we don’t recommend Python-PDFKit unless you know you only need to generate extremely simple documents.

Is the above statement right? I am facing a CSS issue with wkhtmltopdf.